# sp_BlitzFirst doesnt work on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, sp-blitzfirst

```
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 3]
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 120 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 130 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 135 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 139 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 177 [Batch Start Line 3]
Must declare the scalar variable "@BlitzWho".
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 423 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 527 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 539 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 602 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 607 [Batch Start Line 3]
Incorrect syntax near 'vfs'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 624 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 803 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 803 [Batch Start Line 3]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 852 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 984 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 1003 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 1015 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 1076 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 1081 [Batch Start Line 3]
Incorrect syntax near 'vfs'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 1100 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 1130 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 1138 [Batch Start Line 3]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 1206 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 1668 [Batch Start Line 3]
'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 2481 [Batch Start Line 3]
Must declare the scalar variable "@BlitzWho".
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 2486 [Batch Start Line 3]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzFirst, Line 2520 [Batch Start Line 3]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.
```

Comment: I don't belive it works on 2005. That version is, after all, completely unsupported by Microsoft now. Blitzcache also did not work on 2005 so they released a less verbose version that does. Don't believe they've done that. Is plain old blitz not working for you?

Comment: Please see [How to ask](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help us help you : keys to getting good answers](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/). Dumping a wall of error messages does not make a useful question.

Answer (score 5):

From [the procedure body](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_BlitzFirst.sql):

> Only Microsoft-supported versions of SQL Server. Sorry, 2005 and 2000. It may work just fine on 2005, and if it does, hug your parents. Just don't file support issues if it breaks.